# Extract email addresses but remove some tld

Tags: javascript, regex, email

I have a text in a string. I wrote a function that extracts the emails from this string, but I want to remove emails that have particular tld.

For example, remove all email with the tld .xyz

- test@gmail.com --> OK
- test@gmail.xyz --> OUT
- test@gmail.XYZ--> OUT

Here is the function. I don't think the integration of the case insensitive is working in fact. Any help please?

```
function extraction(string) {
    var emails= string.match(/\b[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,6}\b/ig);       
    if (/(xyz|us|porn/i)$/.test(emails)){ 
        return false;
    } else { 
        return emails;
    }   
}
```

Comment: could you give us an exemple of input string ? But not in word format

Comment: Add `regex` tag to your question so more people can see it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could incorporate that logic in your first regular expression with negative look-ahead:

```
\b[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.(?!xyz\b|abc\b|xxx\b)[A-Z]{2,6}\b
```

The inserted part (`(?!xyz\b|abc\b|xxx\b)`) will make sure these 3 extensions (`xyz`, `abc`, `xxx`) are excluded.

No need for a second regex. The offending ones will be excluded right away.

For case insensitivity you need to provide the `i` modifier at the very end of the regex, not halfway:

```
/........./i
```

Answer (score 0):

First if you're trying to restrict some words what you should to do is validate before you put your regular expression.
http://regexr.com/

Second, part of this regular expression is wrong /(xyz|us|porn/i)$/ you put a unescaped forward slash before the **i** what means nothing this is a error in regular expression I'm not a regular expression expert I did this and worked for these words that you was trying to validate
this was my result /xyz|us|porn/ig I put the /ig what means any word upper case or lower case will be searched and the words in global to allow interative search.

I'm learning english, if you not understand ask me with your doubt of my text and I'll answer you.

```js
function extraction(string) {
    var emails= string.match(/\b[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,6}\b/ig);       
    if (/xyz|us|porn/ig.test(emails)){ 
        return false;
    } else { 
        return emails;
    }   
}

 document.write(extraction('test@gmail.com'));
 document.write('<br/>');
 document.write(extraction('test@gmail.xyz'));
 document.write('<br/>');
 document.write(extraction('test@gmail.XYZ'));
```